# How to keep list adding elements not repeating on redis?

Tags: java, caching, redis

For example, a list 1,2,3,4,5 on redis,

server1 want to 1 to 8 so it will add 6,7,8, if it success, the list will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;

server2 want to 1 to 7 so it will add 6,7, it it success, the list will e 1,2,3,4,5,6,7;

you see elements 6,7 is repeating, so actually the list may be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,6,7, or 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,7,8

I'm making a tailking record cache, how to solve this problem? only sorted set? but the cache need lpush

Comment: Yes, SortedSet seems pretty good, you want to sort (Sorted) and no duplicate (Set) ^^

Comment: @azro but sorted set is pretty expensive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use list, then you can add another data structure for get whether a number exists fast : Set.

Make your set's data consistent with your list. When you want to lpush a number to your list, first use SISMEMBER to check whether the number is already in the set(or list), if in, then do not LPUSH, if not in, SADD into set and LPUSH into list. The SISMEMBER is O(1), so it will not add so much time cost.

**one more thing to notice:**

There is a transaction problem because you has two or more server which hold connection to redis. So in above,  some action need to be atomic.
for example , If something happens like this order:

> server 1 check 7 use SISMEMBER =>  return does not exist
>
> server 2 check 7 use SISMEMBER =>  return does not exist
>
> server 1 lpush 7 into list & sadd 7 into set
>
> server 2 lpush 7 into list & sadd 7 into set

Then the list will has two 7s. So how to deal with this ?

At least and best, **the server check a number use SISMEMBER and if not exist, use SADD inser into set, if exists, do nothing to set** should be atomic. If this is atomic, something like above will be like this:

> server 1 check 7 use SISMEMBER =>  return does not exist && sadd 7 into set
>
> server 2 check 7 use SISMEMBER =>  return exists already.
>
> server 1 lpush 7 into list
>
> server 2 do nothing

How to achieve this?  Just use MULTI to make the SISMEMBER and SADD to be atomic.

```
MULTI
   SISMEMBER set n
   SADD set n 
EXEC
```

Then you can use the SISMEMBER's reply to make a decision: lpush or do nothing.
And SADD a duplicate element will be just ignored, so it does not matter.

**EDITED**

And if you want to **lpush many values one time**, you could use the [pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to speed up the SISMEMBER. E.G.  in one pipeline:

```
MULTI
   SISMEMBER set n1
   SISMEMBER set n2
   ...
   SADD set n1,n2,....
EXEC
```

And get every n's result (exist or not) in one reply, then group all the values that need to be lpushed into an array, lpush once together.

Comment: sismember only check one element each times, if server 1 will add 1,2,3,4,5, server 2 will add 3,4,5,6,7, is that mean they will loop a lot?

Comment: Yes, there is a trade off. But because each operation is O(1),  it will not cost too much time. It just cost the network transport time many times. If you want speed up this, you can try the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted sets are the way to go (or even sets) . Lists, by their nature, allow for repeated items. The only way to achieve what you're wanting to do is to use MULTI / LREM / LPUSH / EXEC but this is a bad idea (LREM is O(N) which can be very expensive as the list grows).